# How to access one model attribute from another model to pass in javascript view part in Rails 5?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get the data for the `rider` model from `location` model, and passing it to the javascript part so I can mark each of the riders' location.

I tried to ask the right question regarding the what I intended to do, but no luck.

Here is my `rider.rb` model.

```
class Rider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, as: :profile
end
```

And here is my `location.rb` model.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 geocoded_by :address
 belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true
 validates :profile, :latitude, :longitude, presence: true
end
```

Here is my `controllers.rb`.

```
def show
  @riders = Rider.all
end
```

And here is my `show.html.haml`

```
:javascript
  var map;
  var riders = #{raw @riders.to_json}

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: { lat: 3, lng: 102 },
     zoom: 9
    });
    riders.forEach(function(rider) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: rider.latitude, lng: rider.longitude }, //this line does not work
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: rider.name.split(' ').slice(0,2).join(' '),
       label: rider.name.split(' ').slice(0,2).join(' '),
    });
  }
```

When I `console.log(riders)`, this is the result, missing the `location` attributes that I need.

```
authentication_token: "admin_token_16"
branch_id: 55
deposit_cents: 1000000
email: "leilanimosciskicorkery986@test.com"
id: 19
name: "Leilani Mosciski Corkery"
online: false
order_need_deposit: true
phone:"+9860128134706"
status: "active"
working: false
```

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated!

Comment: you can do preloads for profile on riders while fetching riders from database

Comment: Thanks @user3775217 . Will definitely try that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You are not fetching riders location data in show function.So, replace your show function with one below***

```
def show
  @riders = Rider.joins(:location).select('riders.*','locations.latitude','locations.longitude')
end
```

Comment: @Iqlaas Ismail  try my solution.

Comment: my man, it worked. May I know is the question constructed correctly ? I assume you also stumbled in the same problem before, what was your question ?
P/S: I edited your answer a bit. `location` should be singular. Upvoted. If you happen to travel to Malaysia, give me a message ! Lol You edited it before me!

Comment: @IqlaasIsmail i got it. Actually i thought you have has_many locations. So it was locations. I changed. Upvote my answer if you found it useful.Thank You

Comment: Upvoted. Hopefully it will help some one else. Thanks again.

Comment: @IqlaasIsmail You just accepted as answer but you didnt upvoted.

Comment: @IqlaasIsmail Thank You bro

Comment: Upvoted since I gained more reputation. You are awesome!